# LINQ distinct selection based on a property value

Tags: linq, generics

I have a generic list of countries completely filled with countries instances.

```
List <Country> mylist
```

This list has different instances of countries but some has the same value for the property "name".

How could i make a distinct over the property of the country "name" to get only the countries with different names?

Thanks.

Greets.

Jose.

Comment: You do know Linq has `Distinct`, right? :)

Comment: @bzlm: That doesn't do what the OP wants without writing a custom equality comparer.

Comment: @jon, nothing does anything without doing something. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Jon suggested MoreLINQ, which is obviously fine, but maybe you want to avoid another dependency. In this case, you can use [`Enumerable.Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) with your own `IEqualtyComparer<Country>`:

```
var distinctCountries = myList.Distinct(new EqualityComparerForCountryByName());
//IEqualityComparer
class EqualityComparerForCountryByName : IEqualityComparer<Country> {
     public bool Equals(Country x, Country y) {
         if(Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) { return true; } 
         if(x == null || y == null) { return false; }
         return x.Name == y.Name;
     }

     public int GetHashCode(Country obj) {
         if(obj == null) { return 0; }
         return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what i was searching for. I cannot add nothing to this project. Thanks for the useful info.

Comment: Wish it took a `Comparison<T>`.

Comment: @Marc: It needs the ability to compute a hash code (`Distinct` is basically going to build a hash table as it runs through the list, using `GetHashCode` obviously, and it needs `Equals` to resolve collisions).

Comment: @Jason, I understand. Don't try to crush my dreams. =(

Comment: @Marc: Well: `class EqualityComparerFromComparison<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> { public EqualityComparerFromComparison(Comparision<T> comparer, Func<T, int> getHashCode) { this.comparer = comparer; this.getHashCode = getHashCode; } private readonly Comparison<T> comparer; private readonly Func<T, int> getHashCode; public bool Equals(T x, T y) { return this.comparer(x, y) == 0; } public int GetHashCode(T obj) { return this.getHashCode(obj); } }`. You stil need to specify `GetHashCode`. You could use the trivial one (`obj => 0`), but then everything collides. I typed this inline; sorry for errors.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) with its [`DistinctBy`](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs) method:

```
var distinctCountries = allCountries.DistinctBy(c => c.Name);
```

(You don't have to take all of MoreLINQ of course - you could just copy that one method into your code along with the `ThrowIfNull` extension method, and preserve the licence text appropriately.)

Comment: Looks really nice, the pity is that i cannot add stuff to this project. Its a closed one. Thanks.

Comment: @Jose3d: In what way is taking code from an answer on Stack Overflow significantly different from taking something with a clear and pretty relaxed licence? You can use Open Source software within Closed Source products (depending on the licence) - you just need to heed the licence in terms of attribution.